# Opening a link in a new tab (within a frame setting)

Tags: html

I'm new to html and am trying to design a basic website using frames (I appreciate this is an old method of doing things, but it is easy to navigate and simple, which I can cope with!) To do this, I am using the following code:

```
<FRAMESET frameborder=0, border=1, rows="90,*">
    <FRAME name="top", src="banner.html">
    <FRAMESET rows="*" cols="20%,80%">
        <FRAME name="side", src="sidemenu.html">
    <FRAME name="main", src="welcome.html">
    </FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET><noframes></noframes>
```

Then in my sidemenu with navigation links I have say the link for latest news:

```
<a href="news.html" target="main">News</a>
```

This works fine. However, if a user tries to open the news link in a new tab, they just get the news.html page. Is there any way to have it so that when they try to open this link in a new tab, it opens a new tab containing the banner, the sidemenu and the News page in the main frame?

I hope this makes sense, and thanks for the help.

Comment: What you need to do is detect whether or not you are in a frameset using JavaScript, and if you are not, then change the window's location so that you are.  This is a common problem with framesets, and also applies to users coming to you via search engines and what not.  (Are you sure you still want to use frames?)  See also:  http://www.digitalroom.net/index2.html

Comment: just get rid of frameset and use divs, SO MUCH EASIER

Comment: @SpYk3HH I've hear it is much better to use divs, but as I said, before the weekend I'd never really touched html. Is there a quick and easy way to use divs to do what I've mentioned above, and/or a really good place to learn about divs quickly?

Comment: @DavidWard oh wow. OK, first of all, html/css is so easy, it's barely considered a language.  Secondly, what I mean when I say to use divs, is to use divs with precise css that establishes where you want what.  Third, a good place to get started for new stuff, hit up W3Schools for their [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) tuts. Finally, go to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), make a working example of what you're doing using frameset, and I'll edit it using divs and show you the dif verbatim.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Thanks for that. I've looked at the W3Schools HTML tutorials to design my site, but haven't got as far as the CSS tutorials. I will try to do this when I get some time.

Answer (score 0):

How to open a link in a new browser window try this:

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```